# Closing a webpage in a samsung smart tv app

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

I have a samsung App that is currently streaming a video through a IP camera.

So, I made a app that opens a webpage when I click a certain button (Up arrow).

The code associated to the up arrow is :

`var myWindow = window.open("http://10.0.0.164/mjpg/video.mjpg", "myWindow", "width=200, height=200");`

Now the problem:

When the webpage opens, I don't have any control of the app anymore.

Isn't there a way for me , for example, press the return key to close the the opened window and go back to the app?

I tryed associating the command `Window.close()` to other keys, but no sucess...

Any ideias?

thank you in advance!

Pedro

Comment: Why you use external page? Insert your page source in app.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this so I really don't know how to do that, can you give a link to an example or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is launching the web url launcher of the TV. I think you can try this.

**Add this in HTML-**

```
<div id="webElement" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**On button up click,** try adding the object tag to show the URL (set width and height which you want.)

```
var webElement = jQuery("#webElement");  
webElement.empty();  
var obj = "<object type='text/html' width='1920' height='1080' data='" + urlToShow + "' onerror='Player.onWebElementError();'> </object>";  
webElement.append(obj);  
webElement.show();
```

**On button back click**, you can hide the div and return back to application.

```
var webElement = jQuery("#webElement");  
webElement.empty();  
jQuery("#webElement").hide();
```

Hope it will help you a little bit.

**Updated:**

Add this in your project if JQuery is missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app/javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Check this URL for more info:
http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!
But, I can't open the window even so.. where you wrotte urlToShow I replaced it wi "http://10.0.0.2/..." and then it wouldn't open the window  and say :

0008  Unhandled Error thrown at file:///home/smarttv/Apps/ASDSASD/page/page1.js :31 :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

0009  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

I'm very new at this and i feel like it's a very basic question so, sorry for asking it..

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple: I used an image block from the app framework 2.0, and I set the URL of the IP camera as the src of the image.